# flaten json dynamic in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using this

```
select 'select ' 
      || (select listagg(distinct 'json_col:'||key::text||'::string'||' as '||key::text, ', ')  from GAURAV.PUBLIC.jsondata, lateral flatten(input=>json_col, mode=>'OBJECT')) 
      || ' from GAURAV.PUBLIC.jsondata'
```

but it can't pick keys dynamic

it shows me output like this

[image]

I have Multiple json data in a table
how to flatten it

Comment: Please post a sample JSON in text so people can cut and paste it for testing. It looks like you're building a SQL generator. Based on the sample input, also show the desired output so people can confirm an answer is working right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have a table of json like:

```
 ('{"key_a":"a", "key_b":"b"}'),
 ('{"key_c":"a", "key_d":"b"}')
```

this SQL

```
select 
  'select ' || listagg(distinct 'json_col:'|| f.key::text || '::string as ' || f.key::text, ', ') || ' from GAURAV.PUBLIC.jsondata' as output
from jsondata as jd, 
table(flatten(input=>jd.json_col, mode=>'OBJECT')) f
group by f.seq
```

gives:

| OUTPUT |
| --- |
| select json_col:key_d::string as key_d, json_col:key_c::string as key_c from GAURAV.PUBLIC.jsondata |
| select json_col:key_a::string as key_a, json_col:key_b::string as key_b from GAURAV.PUBLIC.jsondata |

The major points are to loop across the table as a first order selection. And to group the LISTAGG via the SEQ of the flatten which gives a distinct value per row of input, thus if you have 100 input rows, you will get 100 different seq, thus able to keep them separated.

It can be written with that output line split apart also:

```
select 
  'select ' || 
      listagg(distinct 'json_col:'|| f.key::text || '::string as ' || f.key::text, ', ') || 
      ' from GAURAV.PUBLIC.jsondata' as output
from jsondata as jd, 
table(flatten(input=>jd.json_col, mode=>'OBJECT')) f
group by f.seq
```